# IE crash - when copying data from Excel to Sharepoint List

Tags: excel

I have an EXISTING SP List, and am trying to copy / paste data from an xls file into the list.  I have a view created that mirrors the columns I am trying to copy in.  It appears to copy / paste okay, but as soon as I click onto a new row IE crashes.
Any ideas why, and/or what I can do to get around this ?

I tried Chrome instead of IE but Chrome won't allow "datasheet view" of the list for pasting

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this issue before myself. The problem seems to exist when you paste into multiple fields. When it happened to me I added a step. I copy / paste to excel first then copy / paste to SharePoint from the excel.